# Flutter mapping a List<int> to a List<String> throws the error 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, list, dart, casting, mapping

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in
> type cast

```
else if (value is List<int>) {
          prefs.setStringList(
              "itemsToLoanCats", [...value.map((e) => e.toString())]);
        }
```

type of 'value' = `List<int>`

I don't see why this doesn't work, I'm using `.toString()`

STACK TRACE

```
I/flutter (16996): Person This is claiming to be itemsToLoanCats: [0]
I/flutter (16996): saveToPrefs converting GeoPoint...
E/flutter (16996): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
E/flutter (16996): #0      _CastListBase.[] (dart:_internal/cast.dart:99:46)
E/flutter (16996): #1      ListMixin.elementAt (dart:collection/list.dart:78:33)
E/flutter (16996): #2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
E/flutter (16996): #3      StringBuffer.writeAll (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:96:19)
E/flutter (16996): #4      IterableBase.iterableToFullString (dart:collection/iterable.dart:268:14)
E/flutter (16996): #5      ListMixin.toString (dart:collection/list.dart:588:37)
E/flutter (16996): #6      Person.saveToPrefs.<anonymous closure> (package:meloan/model/person.dart:635:72)
E/flutter (16996): #7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
E/flutter (16996): #8      Person.saveToPrefs (package:meloan/model/person.dart:593:20)
E/flutter (16996): #9      _PersonalDetailsScreenState._buildBody.<anonymous closure> (package:meloan/personal/edit_personal_details.dart:1231:30)
E/flutter (16996): #10     _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
E/flutter (16996): #11     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
E/flutter (16996): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
E/flutter (16996): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
E/flutter (16996): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:276:7)
E/flutter (16996): #15     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:163:27)
E/flutter (16996): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:464:20)
E/flutter (16996): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
E/flutter (16996): #18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
E/flutter (16996): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
E/flutter (16996): #20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
E/flutter (16996): #21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
E/flutter (16996): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (16996): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
E/flutter (16996): #24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
E/flutter (16996): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
```

ADDITION:

```
  List<String> encodedList = [];
  for(int intValue in (value as List<int>)) {
    print(LOG + "intValue: $intValue");
    encodedList.add(int.parse(intValue).toString());
  }
```

Doesn't work either, same Exception thrown.

Longer code snippet as requested:

```
 saveToPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    (this.toMap()).forEach((key, value) {
      //print("saveToPrefs entered with key: $key\nvalue: $value");
      if (value != null) {
        if (key == "dbProfilePicPath") {
          print("PERSON " + "should be saving dbProfilePicPath");
        }
        if (value is String) {
          prefs.setString(key, value);
        } else if (key == "position") {
          print("saveToPrefs converting GeoPoint...");
          double latitude = value['geopoint'].latitude;
          double longitude = value['geopoint'].longitude;
          prefs.setDouble("latitude", latitude);
          prefs.setDouble("longitude", longitude);
        } else if (value is List<String>)
          prefs.setStringList(key, value);
        else if (value is double)
          prefs.setDouble(key, value);
        else if (value is int)
          prefs.setInt(key, value);
        else if (value is bool)
          prefs.setBool(key, value);
        else if (value is Map<String, String>) {
          // needs to be stored as a list
          List<String>? list = [];
          value.forEach((key, value) {
            list.add("$key:$value");
          });
          prefs.setStringList(key, list);
        } else if (value is Map<String, bool>) {
          // e.g. .Charateristics needs to be stored as a list
          List<String>? list = [];
          value.forEach((key, value) {
            list.add("$key:${value.toString()}");
          });
          prefs.setStringList(key, list);
        } else if (value is Map<String, dynamic>) {
          // loanItemFinancials / loanItemDetails?
          //prefs.setString('loanItemDetails', json.encode(value));
        } else if (value is List<int>) {
          // itemsToLoanCats, each loaning category encoded to int
          value = value.cast<int>();
          print(LOG + 'This is claiming to be itemsToLoanCats: ${value.toString()}');

          prefs.setStringList("itemsToLoanCats", value.map((el) => el.toString()).toList());
          //prefs.setStringList("itemsToLoanCats", [...value.map((e) => e.toString())]);
        }
```

Comment: it is supposed to work, btw does creating new list variable work?

Comment: What is the stacktrace?  Are you sure that the error originated from this line?  The error indicates that a `String` is being passed where an `int` is expected.

Comment: @jamesdlin stack trace attached, more context code added.

Comment: Show the code from `meloan/model/person.dart` around lines 592 and 635.  I don't see anything in the stacktrace that obviously corresponds to the code you've shown.

Comment: @jamesdlin done. Thanks for your continued attention.

Comment: OK, well much of the day spent on this, if I set value to value = [1,2.3] that works. So it's the value it's receiving, seemingly [0], that's causing it to break. I'm not sure where it's got this value from. It seems to pass the filter above it `value is List<int>` and if I cast `value = value.cast<int>();` it still fails. This is extremely odd.

Comment: Does the error and stacktrace you've shown correspond to the exact code you've shown?  The code you've shown seems to include other changes.  Additionally, the line you commented out (`"itemsToLoanCats", value.map((e) => [...value.map((e) => e.toString())])`) isn't the same as what you originally claimed.  Which is it?

Comment: I removed a print statement I think, I'll fix all the stuff above it's probably 1 line out of sync, but I'll do it all over, thanks for your kind attention. It does work on hard coded list<int>, but behaves strangely with [0], which looks like a list<int>.

Comment: I've type-tested `value` and `CastList<String, int>` is somehow managing to sneak through the filter `if(value is List<int>)`. So I think that must be the problem. But I little know what it means and know less how to solve it.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, if you want some creds, you're welcome to post why my solution solved it, I don't fully understand how Dart's casts are functioning / dysfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the list into json first.

```
encodedList = json.encode(value);
debugPrint(encodedList.toString());

prefs.setString('itemsToLoanCats', encodedList);
```

Comment: Needs to be a List<String> I save. Not a simple plain String. Other things in many places rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

OK solved. So I discovered the type of `value` wasn't compatible with my map to String code.

Turns out `value` was assigned using `.cast<int>()`, this doesn't produce a proper List, it's a Map? `CastList<String, int>`.

Anyway, I had to delve earlier in my code and reconfigure how this variable is assigned when extracted from `prefs`.

`(prefs.getStringList('itemsToLoanCats') ?? []).map(int.parse).toList();`

Solved it.

Crikey! Thanks for the attention and encouragement all. If you want to post an answer explaining why `.cast<int>` produces a map and can't be treated like a `List<int>` then I'll give the answer credit.

Extremely strange it reports as `List<int>` but refuses to behave as such